# Browserify jQuery is not defined with Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, browserify

I would like use Browserify with Foundation, but i've error after compile my JS :

```
Erreur : ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I've see this [setting](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/24951-foundation-with-browserify) but no result.

My shim :

```
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/foundation-sites/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "foundation": "./node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jquery": "jQuery",
    "foundation": "foundation"
},
```

And my app.js :

```
global.$ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var foundation = require('foundation');

// Imports
import '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js';
import { gridShow, gridShortcut } from './app.grid.js';
```

Do you have any idea why i've this error ? It's when i import mediaQuery

Thank you !